# Активные пункты в дереве меню

Tags: php, рекурсия, меню

Имеется скрипт отрисовки дерева меню на php:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_base) or 
die("Ошибка соединения: " . mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM gallery_albums";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[$row['id']]= $row;
    }
}else{
    echo "doesn't work";
}

function view_cat ($dataset) {

    $arr = "";
    foreach ($dataset as $menu) {
        $active = ($_GET['album'] == $menu['id']) ? 'active' : '';
        $arr .= '<li class="' . $active . '"><a>'.$menu["name"].'</a>';
        if(!empty($menu['childs'])) {
            $arr .= '<ul>';
                $arr .= view_cat($menu['childs']);
            $arr .= '</ul>';
        }
        $arr .= '</li>';
    }
    return $arr;
}

function mapTree($dataset) {
    $tree = array();

    foreach ($dataset as $id=>&$node) {
        if (!$node['parent']) {
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        }else {
            $dataset[$node['parent']]['childs'][$id] = &$node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

$allMenu = mapTree($data);
print_r($allMenu);
```

Таким образом, мы получаем дерево меню для сайта с бесконечным количеством потомков.
**Основной вопрос:** добавлять класс "active" к тегу 'li' по всей ветке. Допустим, активный пункт - на 3 уровне, нужно, чтобы класс добавлялся ко 2 и к 1 уровням, а не только к 3.
Пример верстки на выходе:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">
        Пункт 1
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                Подпункт 1
                <ul>
                    <li class="active">Подподпункт 1</li>
                    <li>Подподпункт 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Подпункт 2</li>
            <li>Подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Пункт 2</li>
    <li>Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

У меня получается сделать только на 1 уровень. А именно: если id альбома в итерации `foreach` равен GET-параметру то подставляем в `$active = 'active'` Т.е. если мы находимся на "Подподпункт 1" то только он и активен, а родителям не добавляется класс.

Comment: отделите процедуру генерации структуры от вывода. Сначала пройдитесь и проставьте классы активных, а потом уже выводите. При постановке вы в крайнем пункте устаналиваете active, затем должны из рекурсии вернуть признак того, что активный найден. и дальше идут возвраты из рекурсий и расстановки классов текущим пунктам. а-ля если вернулось true, то текущему ставим active и на выход.

Comment: совместить это с выводом у вас не получится, ибо `<li>`, куда надо добавить класс уже выведен.

Comment: Правильно понимаю, нужно при построении дерева определить активных? Ну, допустим, добавить элемент массива - `active`??

Comment: да, как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, решил пока таким образом: написал отдельную функцию, которая перед построением дерева `mapTree` будет проводить обработку и добавлять элемент массива `active` всем родителям и самому элементу.

```
function checkActive(&$row, $currAlbum) {
    if(!empty($currAlbum)) {
        foreach($row as &$item) {
            if($item['id'] == $currAlbum) {
                $item['galleri-active'] = ' active';

                if($item['parent']) {
                    checkActive($row, $item['parent']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Для первоначальной версии пойдет!

В будущем займусь рефакторингом! (с) Какой-то не очень великий программист